# Android - Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:WindowTitleBackground'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, merge, android-support-library

I imported an old Eclipse project into Android Studio and I'm trying my best to get it to compile while still supporting SdkVersion 4.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.name"
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

**Errors:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
C:\Users\me\WORK\ORIGINAL\original_gradle_made\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:WindowTitleBackground'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:WindowTitleBackground'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Anyone know what I'm missing or need to change?

Comment: **minSdkVersion 4** not sure that exists its 2017 you are targeting too much  audience use that at least to 14 or 15 // why you want to use min as 4 ? If seems like a framework error to me @_@

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `targetSdkVersion 21` to -> `targetSdkVersion 13` . And then `clean` and `rebuild` the project.

Comment: please edit your answer .It should be `minSdkVersion `

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya from some other answers, I found the issue can be caused by setting a higher target sdk, I am waiting till he tries it to see if it works !

Comment: @OBX I tried changing the `targetSdkVersion` to 13 and nothing changes. I also tried changing the `minSdkVersion`

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project with the options I needed. I added the v4 support to the build.gradle file and I copy and pasted that to the existing project and it took care of my problem.